# Как задизайнить несколько CrudRepository в одном сервисе?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Есть несколько репозиториев для разных сущьностей:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Integer> {
}

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}

public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Integer> {
}
```

И есть места в на уровне сервисов, где нужно сипользовать сразу все три (а если их 10 будет...). И получется что нужно создавать инстансы каждого из них полях. Что-то вроде такого:

```
@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {
    @Autowired
    private final ItemRepository itemRepo;

    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private final RoleRepository roleRepo;

    ...и тут их использовать...
}
```

Мне кажется или костыль? Как в таких случаях поступают? Может их как-то объединить? Может быть есть какой-то паттерн или в целом подход к решению таких ситуаций. Потому что случай как мне **кажется** типичный. Подскажите как это решается. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Представим, что в вашем сервисе 10 репозиториев, и есть два метода. Первый метод испульзует репозитории с номерами 1-5, а второй - 6-10. В таком случае, следует сделать два сервиса, в которых будет по одному методу. В первый сервис поместить репозитории 1-5, а во второй репозитории 6-10.
2. Изпользуя ваш пример, можно представить, что логику авторизации мы будем реализовывать при помощи **RoleRepository** и **UserRepository** (лучше решать такие задачи средствами **Spring Security**). Тогда, руководствуясь **принципом единой ответственности**, лучше будет создать отдельный класс для логики авторизации:

   ```
   @Service
   class AuthorizationServiceImpl implements AuthorizationService{

   @Autowired
   private final RoleRepository roleRepo;

   @Autowired
   private final UserRepository userRepo;

   ...
   }

   @Service
   public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

   @Autowired
   private final ItemRepository itemRepo;

   @Autowired
   private final AuthorizationService authService;

   ...и тут их использовать...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте применить паттер [Facade](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), он и создан для решения таких проблем.